# How can I fix lagg in Starling Arkanoid Game?

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I made a arkanoid game and sometimes the ball laggs is there a simple fix to this? Im not sure what code to post because I got a lot of code

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot a reason for that... It's probably a framerate problem. You need to install or code a tool to check it. 
If the framerate sometimes falls you need to inspect your main game loop and find the reason.

It's impossible to help you more with so few details.

Comment: my main gameloop has a lot of code in it so its hard to post I used a tool which trace the fps it says 61/60. The tool is the same as in this tutorial [link](http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/starting-with-starling-ep-1-intro-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

To find the cause of an unknown performance issue, use the free Adobe Scout tool.

Once you get it running, you should see a spike in the graph it produces at the moment the game lags. Inspecting this spike should reveal the cause of the lag, whether it be garbage collection, a very intensive method, or something else.

Here's a 'getting started' link:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html